# spring web socket server and react client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket, sockjs, spring-web

i have to develop a web socket server with spring that send to the client a message avery 5 sec. The client is written in react js. This is my server code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class TestwsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestwsApplication.class, args);
    }
}



@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chatWS").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
    }
```

This is my scheduler that send to the channel /topic/message a message every 5 sec

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    @Autowired
    WebSocketListener listener;

    int i=0;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {

        if (i==0){

            listener.pushSystemStatusToWebSocket("ok");
            i=1;
        }else{
            listener.pushSystemStatusToWebSocket("errore");
            i=0;
        }



    }
}
```

This is my service used by the scheduler to send the message to the clients

```
    @Service
public class WebSocketListener {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate webSocket;


    @Async
    public void pushSystemStatusToWebSocket (String newStatus){
        System.out.println("inviooooooooooooooooooooooooooo");

        webSocket.convertAndSend("/topic/messages", newStatus);
    }

}
```

This is my react component

```
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            clickCount: 0,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        // this is an "echo" websocket service
        console.log('didmount')
        var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/chatWS');


        sock.onopen = function() {
            console.log('open socket ');
            sock.send('test');
        };

        sock.onmessage = function(e) {
            console.log('message');
            console.log('message', e.data);
            sock.close();
        };

        sock.onclose = function() {
            console.log('close');
        };
    }
```

on the log i see only the post open socket ... i dont see any log inserted in onmessage... so the client did not receive the message. Why ? Can you help me ?
Thanks
Esoni

Comment: Your scheduler and service class happens to have the same code. Please update it

Comment: sorry.. i've updated it now

Comment: Did you solve this situation?? I have a similar issue on the same environment (Spring Boot + React)